# RestSharp with unknown field names

Tags: json.net, restsharp

In the JSON response, I get an array named `Results` that has items with field names that are not always the same name so I can't use a class. Is there a way to parse each array item as string?

Comment: Can you add some sample JSON to understand more details?

Comment: "ResultCount": 849,
    "Results": [
        {
            "DocID": "OV00000017",
            "NL Review Complete": {  // This May be "NL Reviewed" Some times or "Reviewed"
                "Name": "1.1 Review Complete",
            },
            "NL Relevant/Responsive": [  //This may be "NL Responsiveness" Some times or "Responsive" Or "Relevant" 
                {       // It may not be an array some times 
                    "Name": "1.2 Relevant",
                },
    ................................

Comment: I need to query the JSON without knowing the field names. Thx